# need to query 2 MySQL tables with COUNT(*) condition

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables (cycles and merged_cycles). "cycles" has 2 fields I need to target (userid and cycleid) and "merged_cycles" also has 2 targeted fields (cycleid1 and cycleid2). I need to know all cycles.userid that have more than one record in "cycles", so long as the corresponding cycles.cycleid for any matching record does not appear in any record in "merged_cycles" in either merged-cycles.cycleid1 OR merged_cycles.cycleid2. I currently have it working using 2 different queries, but i was curious if it could be done in one. Here's what i have tried so far:

```
SELECT cycles.cycleid, cycles.userid, cycles.COUNT(*), 
       merged_cycles.cycleid1, merged_cycles.cycleid2
FROM cycles,merged_cycles
WHERE merged_cycles.cycleid1 != cycles.cycleid && merged_cycles.cycleid2 != cycles.cycleid
GROUP BY cycles.userid
HAVING cycles.count(*) > 1
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please include an example of the queries you used, input data and expected result. It is quite hard to understand what you are trying to do from your description. Would you like to get the requirements from your team lead in this format?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT c.cycleid
FROM cycles c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM merged_cycles mc
                  WHERE c.cycleid IN (mc.cycleid1, mc.cycleid2)
                 )
GROUP BY c.userid
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: UNION ALL in the subquery or two NOT EXISTS conditions would probably be faster.

Comment: `UNION ALL` probably would *not* be faster.  Two `NOT EXISTS` would be if there are indexes on each of the two columns.

Comment: Thank you, this did not work for me, but I am moving past it.  I have it working with 2 different queries, and i may need to expand this function even further, so I will back-burner this "single query" thing for now.  Thanks all for your time!